# How to JOIN with SUM() in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I would like to make the following style table output using CouchDB and linked documents:

```
+----------------+------------+--------------------+
|     Title      |    Date    | Number of Comments |
+----------------+------------+--------------------+
| Hello World    | 2000-01-01 |                301 |
| Next Question? | 1999-03-04 |                 11 |
| Final Post     | 1992-04-01 |                 64 |
+----------------+------------+--------------------+
```

I have documents that look like this for posts:

```
{ _id : 'hello-world', title : 'Hello World', date : '2000-01-01', type : 'post' }
```

and for comments:

```
{ _id : 'some-comment', title : 'Great post!', postid: 'hello-world', type : 'comment' }
{ _id : 'some-comment2', title : 'Poor quality', postid: 'final-post', type : 'comment' }
```

How can I accomplish this?  I would prefer to use a single map/reduce.

Comment: You can't really do that with one query. You can use a map/reduce to get the number of comments per post and then query couch to get the informations about those posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this for myself in case any one else has this question.  I think my misunderstand comes from my being used to SQL.

Basically, my options are:

1. Create a design document view (`comments-by-post`) that will give me the post._id as the key and the # number of comments for that post.  Then, I can stitch this together with the posts obtained by a Mango query or another view in my programming language.
2. Alternatively, **and probably more correctly**, I can just create a property called `numberOfComments` on the post object and update it every time someone comments.  This feels wrong from an SQL perspective, but I believe the flexibility of the document database lends itself to this.

I'm choosing to do #1 to begin with and experiment with #2.